# IMAP Subject UTF-8 with german umlauts

Tags: node.js, base64, imap

I use the `imap` with nodejs and fetch some E-Mails. All works fine. The `imap` is a low level lib and gives all the data without any encoding to my application.

The **subject** correctly is "GMX Täßt". I received this `=?UTF-8?Q?GMX_T=C3=A4=C3=9Ft?=` from the lib. All fine at this time.
If I wanna convert it back to "GMX Täßt" (I have tried many things.." I got **GMX T├ñ├ƒt** withtout umlauts.

```
stringFromSubject = "=?UTF-8?Q?GMX_T=C3=A4=C3=9Ft?=";

decodeURIComponent(
      stringFromSubject.replace(/=([0-9A-F]{2})/g, "%$1")
    ).replace(/_/g, " ");
```

[Here](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) is the link of the lib. Can anyone help to convert it back "correctly"?

Comment: A quick [Search for "javascript convert utf-7"](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+convert+utf-7) gets you https://github.com/kkaefer/utf7, and also [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60793606), which includes a hacked-together solution

Comment: The problem is the Windows "Shell"! (or command promt). It doesn't show the umlauts, emoji correctly. If I save all into a simple text file with node's `writeFileSync` all will be shown correctly...

Comment: Yes, Windows console has poor non-ASCII character support. I use [Windows Terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal), which has better support, plus other better things as well

Comment: Windows Terminal under the hood uses PowerShell and Command Promt, too or doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. But the limitation is not of PowerShell/CMD themselves, but of the Windows Console which hosts them - and Windows Terminal replaces that.

Comment: That is not UTF-7 (whcih is only used for IMAP folder names).  That's RFC 2047 Encoded Words.  The UTF-8 is the charset, and the Q means it's using Quoted-Printable encoding for the non-ascii portions.  It looks like [`parseHeader`](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) can decode encoded-words.

Answer (score 0):

E-mail processing is all about encapsulation, layers and compatibility. At the very bottom of the stack, there's the historical RFC 822 (then RFC 2822, and these days [RFC 5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322)) which says how ASCII text is encoded into e-mail headers. On top of that, there's MIME which defines in [RFC 2047](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047.html) how Unicode text can be encoded using just ASCII letters, for use in e-mail headers.

What you get from your `imap` library is a text prior to RFC 2047 decoding. To convert that to Unicode (and to merge these `encoded-word`s into a piece of text), follow the process described in that document (or use a library that implements this functionality for you). Do **not** use ["URI decoding" from RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986.html#section-2.1) for that; that's a different standard which is solving an unrelated problem.